# Formula to check if a point is inside a a right triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I am developing an app that show some geology diagrams as Streckeisen:

[image]

I need that when the user clicks in a field the corresponding rock sheet opens. The approach I am using is to store the coordinates inside the image that has been clicked.

I think the better approach is to divide the fields in squares and/or right triangles. I have no troubles to check with code if the user has clicked in the squares, but I need to add a formula for the right triangle shapes.

Can you help me with the formula needed to show if the coordinates clicked are inside the right triangle?

[image]

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-triangle-or-not/ This may be too long and inefficient, there might be a more elegant approach. Alternatively, if you can implement something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828741/finding-whether-a-point-is-within-a-right-angle-triangle#3828802, it might work for your purpose.

Comment: 1. Rescale your right triangle and move it so that the new vertices are (0,0), (1,0) and (0,1). 2. Check if your rescaled and moved point is inside this new triangle, by checking its coordinates -- if they are non-negative and less than or equal to 1.

Comment: @Universal_learner -- I am not referring to your diagram, which is very clear. I was describing the algorithm. I am suggesting that you compute a transformation which will take your triangle to a simpler triangle - the one that I mentioned. Then apply this transformation to the point you want to check whether it is inside or not. The advantage is that it is very easy to check if a point is in that special triangle, whose vertices are (0,0),(1,0) and (0,1).

Comment: @AVS The Java code is perfect and my Android app is written in Java, thank you very much. It simplifies my example as I need several triangles and some of them are not rigth-angle triangles. I can divide all into triangles for example for *Monzo-granite* I can use three triangles instead of two with a rectangle

Comment: *Deleted comment before uniquesolution aclaration, sorry. I wasn't sure if I should change something in my diagram

Comment: @AVS I read the comments. It may lead to some errors, but I need *grosso modo* the user has clicked inside the triangle, so I think the code will serve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your diagram, to check if $(x,y)$ is inside the triangle (not on the boundary but strictly inside): Check the inequalities
$$x_0<x<x_1 \\ y_0 < y < y_1 \\ 
x_0y+xy_1+x_1y_0 > x_1y_1+xy_0+x_1y.$$
[note the first two lines are each two inequalities e.g. $x_0 < x$ and $x < x_1$.] The third inequality comes from a known method to determine whether a triangle is oriented in a counterclockwise order, here the ordered triangle $(x_0,y_1),(x,y),(x_1,y_0).$